# ListView Android "has stopped"

Tags: android, listview

i'm trying to make a listview aplication, and since yesterday this happens to me, the aplication stop unexpectedly... here's my code:

```
package com.example.listview;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ListView myListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.myListView);
    final EditText myEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.myEditText);
    final ArrayList<String> todoItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    final ArrayAdapter<String> aa;
    aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_main, todoItems);
    myListView.setAdapter(aa);

    myEditText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
           if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
             if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER) || (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
               todoItems.add(0, myEditText.getText().toString());
               aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
               myEditText.setText("");
               return true;
           }
        return false;
        }
   });


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

this application does a list with the "day task", and you put this "day task" on EditText

edit:
here's the activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/myListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp" >
</ListView>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/myEditText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:ems="10" />
```

Comment: Please post your LogCat and `activity_main.xml` file so we can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without your LogCat we can only *guess* at what the problem is, but I see one potential error with your adapter:

```
new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_main, todoItems);
```

This is the wrong layout to use in your adapter, because it would create multiple ListViews inside the first ListView... You should pass a simple layout like:

```
new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, todoItems);
```

Comment: hey Sam! Thanks! thats the error, i'm learning how to code java/android and i was puting the wrong "layout"

Comment: Glad I could help, please click the checkmark to mark this question as solved.